# Labeling your random forest class probabilities into low, medium, high risk

Tags: r, random-forest

I have an insurance fraud data set with predicted class probabilities using random forest. The data set is a mix of numerical and categorical variables.

I want to further label them into low risk, medium risk, high risk on the basis of these class probabilities.

How can clustering be used in this case? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: What does the distribution of your predictions look like?

Comment: Since it is a insurance fraud dataset. The distribution is highly skewed towards one class. So it is highly skewed towards right tail.

Comment: Alright, if you have a unimodal variable, there's no clustering algorithm that will tell you what is high risk or low risk since there's no logical grouping based on the data alone. You're going to need to define for yourself what high and low risk are, pick your own thresholds, and then cut the prediction variable based on that.